# System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute -- The relative virtual path './images/gift-card.jpg' is not allowed here

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to convert the relative path to the absolute path with System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute()

But I got this error:

The relative virtual path './images/gift-card.jpg' is not allowed here.

By the way, the file structure is

**this code is in a .cs file and this file is in the same folder (let's say /root) with other .aspx files. The image is in a folder, /root/images/**

Any ideas?

**ps:
even I change the path to '~/images/gift-card.jpg'  it still throws an exception: Unhandled Exception without further information.**

Comment: `~/` is correct.  If you still get an exception, that means you have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: @SLaks my code is in a .cs file and this file is in the same folder (let's say root) with other .aspx files. The image is in a folder, root/images/. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

**Server.MapPath("~/path/file.ext")**

This perfectly solved my problem and it was the method I was looking for.

Thank you all for your input.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

`VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute()` is a static function which is not aware of any local cotnext such as the directory of the current request.

Therefore, you cannot pass it a relative path.
Instead, you must pass it an absolute application-relative path, beginning with `~/`.

See the remarks in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150160.aspx):

> An application absolute path is one where the application path is used
>   instead of the root operator (the tilde [~]).
>
> If virtualPath is:
>
> - Absolute, the ToAbsolute method returns the virtual path unchanged.
> - Application relative, the ToAbsolute method appends the current application virtual directory path to the beginning of the
>     virtualPath. For example, the current application virtual directory
>     path can be accessed from the AppDomainAppVirtualPath property.
> - Not rooted, the ToAbsolute method raises an ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception.

Comment: @SLake, hi SLaks, I have tried, another exception. Please see my post in the PS section, thx

Comment: @Franva: What does the exception say?